# How to write in specific File using log4j appenders

Tags: spring, log4j

I am working on Spring and using log4j for logging. Now I have one specific requirement to log something in specific file, here is audit file. Following is the configuration that I am using for that.

Tried to using access that specific file using following syntax but both are not working and shows following syntax.

```
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("AUDIT_APPENDER");
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("audit");
```

[image]

Configuration:
  name: Default
  status: "debug"

Properties:
    Property:
      name: base_pattern_layout
      value: "%d{DEFAULT}{GMT+0} %X{user-identifier}"

Appenders:

```
RollingFile:
  - name: Test1_APPENDER
    fileName: ${LOG_DIR}/service.log
    filePattern: ${LOG_DIR}/test.%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
    PatternLayout:
      Pattern: "app > ${base_pattern_layout} %-5level %logger{8}:%line - %msg%n"
    Policies:
      TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
        interval: "1"
    DefaultRolloverStrategy:
      Delete:
        basePath: ${LOG_DIR}
        IfFileName:
          glob: "service.*.log.gz"
        IfLastModified:
          age: "1d"
  - name: AUDIT_APPENDER
    fileName: ${LOG_DIR}/audit.log
    filePattern: ${LOG_DIR}/audit.%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
    PatternLayout:
      Pattern: "aud > ${base_pattern_layout} %-5level %msg%n"
    Policies:
      TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
        interval: "1"
    DefaultRolloverStrategy:
      Delete:
        basePath: ${LOG_DIR}
        IfFileName:
          glob: "audit.*.log.gz"
        IfLastModified:
          age: "1d"

Console:
  - name: Test1_APPENDER
    target: SYSTEM_OUT
    PatternLayout:
      Pattern: "app > ${base_pattern_layout} %logger{8}:%line - %msg%n"
  - name: AUDIT_APPENDER
    target: SYSTEM_OUT
    PatternLayout:
      Pattern: "aud > ${base_pattern_layout} - %msg%n"
```

Loggers:

```
Root:
  level: INFO
  AppenderRef:
    ref: EXT_APPENDER

Logger:
  - name: com.test
    additivity: false
    level: debug
    AppenderRef:
      ref: Test1_APPENDER
  - name: audit
    additivity: false
    level: INFO
    AppenderRef:
      ref: AUDIT_APPENDER
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass Class in getLogger method as below

```
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);
```

Create log4j.properties file and place it in resource folder.
add below content

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Comment: I took help from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579187/writing-audit-logs-using-log4j  and if I will attach this logger with class how I will say in which file it should write.